# How do I allow regular users to open an installer shortcut with administrative privileges?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I work at a college, and our testing center uses a program (Pearson VUE) that can only be run by an administrator account. However, the PCs auto-login as a very restricted, generic student account. We currently use a janky script to switch accounts, open the program, then switch back, so the student can take their test. I'm trying to set it up so that students can just use a desktop shortcut to run the program as an administrator. The PCs are Windows 10, and members of a domain.

The shortcut that is created when the program is installed is an installer shortcut (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/editing-installer-shortcuts), so I can't edit it or see the shortcut's Target. I did manage to get a path to an executable by opening the .lnk with Notepad++. The filepath is C:\Windows\Installer{2672D1EC-6121-4131-AD8C-FCC351B650C0}\PreRun.exe.

I created a new shortcut with the settings below, but it still isn't working.

Target: %systemroot%\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:domain\username /savecred "C:\Windows\Installer{2672D1EC-6121-4131-AD8C-FCC351B650C0}\PreRun.exe"

Start in: C:\Windows\Installer{2672D1EC-6121-4131-AD8C-FCC351B650C0}

I've also tried just going to the new shortcut's Properties, Shortcut, Advanced, then checking the "Run as administrator" box, but that doesn't seem to be doing anything either.

Am I missing something? Alternatively, is there another way to accomplish the same thing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The point of requiring administrative privileges for some operations is that it shouldn't be possible to invoke them from regular user accounts. So two options: 1. Is it possible to install the program all the way, so that users can start the program without being required to perform further installation steps? 2. Is it possible to vote with your wallet and select a sanely written testing platform?

Comment: I wish we could just use different software, but it's Pearson VUE, which is used for a bunch of different certification tests that we proctor. The software is installed on the PCs, so I'm not sure why it requires admin rights or if there are any further installation steps to do.

Comment: I think the appropriate course of action would be to contact Pearson VUE.

Comment: How about running VUE inside a throwaway virtual machine?  (And I do hope these machines aren't being used for anything you care about, because as it stands this is a gigantic security hole!)